# In assembly why can't a hexadecimal number be printed without shifting?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

This code is taken from an online example.
Let's say I have the variable I want to print in my DL.

```
DISPLAY_HEX PROC NEAR
    MOV BL,DL   

    MOV BH,0    
    MOV CL,4    

    SHL BX,CL   
    MOV DL,BH   

    CALL ONE_DIGIT  

    MOV CL,4    
    SHR BL,CL   
    MOV DL,BL   

    CALL ONE_DIGIT  

    RET     
DISPLAY_HEX ENDP


ONE_DIGIT PROC NEAR

    CMP DL,9    
    JA LETTER   

    ADD DL,48
    JMP NEXT    

LETTER: ADD DL, 'A'-10  

NEXT:   MOV AH,02H  
    INT 21H 

END:    RET     
ONE_DIGIT ENDP
```

Why the shifts? Can't it be printed like a decimal?
Also, why is both **SHR** and **SHL** being used here?

Comment: You can't print a decimal directly either. You need to convert to text. It just so happens that every 4 bits is a hex digit so you can use shift instead of division that you normally would. From a quick glance the code is wrong, because it prints the same digit twice. But I didn't have my coffee yet ;)

Comment: Ah okay, it prints the two digits fine, the `shr` is to undo the `shl` so the low 4 bits end up back where they started.

Comment: Thank you jester, I think I got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In base16 (hex) you've got 16 possible digits (`0..F`), so it takes exactly 4 bits to represent one hexadecimal digit (log2(16) == 4). Here I'm talking about digits in the sense of the values (`0..F`, or `0..15` in base10), not the ASCII characters.

So one byte can hold two hexadecimal digits. Let's say that `DL` holds the following bits: `XXXXYYYY` (where each `X` and `Y` is either a binary 0 or 1).

First the 16-bit register `BX` is shifted 4 bits to the left. `BX` consists of `BL` (least significant byte) and `BH` (most significant byte). `BH` has been set to 0, and `BL` contains the input, so prior to the shift `BX` will contain the bits `00000000XXXXYYYY`. And after the shift it will contain `0000XXXXYYYY0000`.
Then the most significant byte of `BX` (i.e. `BH`, which now contains `0000XXXX`) is moved to `DL`, converted to a character, and printed.

For the second part `BL`, which now contains `YYYY0000` is shifted 4 bits to the right, resulting in `0000YYYY`. And then that value is converted to a character and printed.

Comment: Woah! Thank you much for taking the time to explain, that was awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is massively overcomplicated, no wonder it was confusing.  It's getting the high nibble of DL by left-shifting BX, so the two nibbles are split into BH and BL, but the nibble in BL is in the top 4 bytes.

You need one shift to get the high 4 bits down to the bottom of a register.

Using AND to keep only the low 4 bits would be easier, and *much* faster on a real 8086 (where each count of a shift took a clock cycle, unlike modern CPUs with barrel-shifter ALUs that can do arbitrary shifts in 1 clock cycle).

This is a simpler and easier-to-understand implementation, which is also more compact and thus faster and better on a real 8086.

```
; Input in DL
; clobbers AX, CL, DX
DISPLAY_HEX PROC NEAR
    mov  dh, dl          ; save a copy for later

    mov  cl, 4
    shr  dl, cl          ; extract the high nibble into an 8-bit integer

    CALL ONE_DIGIT  

    and  dh, 0Fh         ; clear the high nibble, keeping only the low nibble
    mov  dl, dh          ; and pass it to our function
    CALL ONE_DIGIT  

    RET     

DISPLAY_HEX ENDP
```

To save code size,  `mov dl, 0Fh` / `and dl, dh` would be only 2 bytes per instruction, instead of 3 for `and dh, 0Fh`, and it takes the `mov` off the critical path for out-of-order execution.

The implementation of `ONE_DIGIT` also has needlessly-complex branching.  (Often you'd implement nibble -> ASCII with a lookup table, but it only needs one branch, not two.  Running an extra `add` is cheaper than an extra `jmp`.)

```
; input: DL = 0..15 integer
; output: AL = ASCII hex char written
; clobbers = AH    
ONE_DIGIT PROC NEAR
    CMP   DL,9    
    JBE   DIGIT   

    ADD   DL, 'A'-10  - '0'
DIGIT:
    ADD   DL, '0'

    MOV AH,02H  
    INT 21H      ; write char to stdout, return in AL.  Checks for ^c/break
    RET
ONE_DIGIT ENDP
```

We could have done `ADD  dx, '00'` (and changed the `cmp`) to operate on both nibbles at once (after isolating them each in DH and DL).

We could also hoist the `MOV AH,02H`, because [`int 21h`/`ah=2` doesn't modify AH.](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah02).

If we cared about performance, we'd create a 2-character string and use one `int 21h` system call to print both digits at once, though.